Implement Biometric Passkey Login for Smart Contract Authentication Using X and Y Coordinates in React Native?
We attempted various approaches using different npm packages, such as react-native-passkey and @turnkey/react-native-passkey-stamper, but these solutions didn't fully address our requirements for obtaining X and Y coordinates in a mobile app with React Native. Finally, we customized the implementation using react-native-biometrics to generate the public key and extract coordinates.
Here's an example of our implementation:
import ReactNativeBiometrics, { BiometryTypes } from 'react-native-biometrics';

const rnBiometrics = new ReactNativeBiometrics({
    allowDeviceCredentials: true
});

export const BiometricUtils = {
    // Check if biometrics is available
    isBiometricAvailable: async () => {
        try {
            const { available, biometryType } = await rnBiometrics.isSensorAvailable();
            return {
                available,
                biometryType,
                error: null
            };
        } catch (error) {
            return {
                available: false,
                biometryType: null,
                error: error.message
            };
        }
    },

    // Create keys and get public key
    createKeys: async () => {
        try {
            const { publicKey } = await rnBiometrics.createKeys();
            return {
                publicKey,
                error: null
            };
        } catch (error) {
            return {
                publicKey: null,
                error: error.message
            };
        }
    },

    // Delete existing keys
    deleteKeys: async () => {
        try {
            const result = await rnBiometrics.deleteKeys();
            return {
                success: result,
                error: null
            };
        } catch (error) {
            return {
                success: false,
                error: error.message
            };
        }
    },

    // Check if keys exist
    checkKeys: async () => {
        try {
            const { keysExist } = await rnBiometrics.biometricKeysExist();
            return {
                exists: keysExist,
                error: null
            };
        } catch (error) {
            return {
                exists: false,
                error: error.message
            };
        }
    },

    // Create signature using biometric authentication
    createSignature: async (payload) => {
        try {
            const { success, signature } = await rnBiometrics.createSignature({
                promptMessage: 'Sign with biometrics',
                payload
            });
            return {
                success,
                signature,
                error: null
            };
        } catch (error) {
            return {
                success: false,
                signature: null,
                error: error.message
            };
        }
    }
};

After generating the public key, we obtain coordinates as follows:
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';

export const KeyCoordinates = {
    // Convert public key to coordinates
    getCoordinates: (publicKey) => {
        try {
            // Remove '0x' prefix and any whitespace
            const cleanKey = publicKey.replace('0x', '').trim();

            // Convert base64 to hex if the key is in base64 format
            let hexKey = cleanKey;
            try {
                if (cleanKey.match(/^[A-Za-z0-9+/]+={0,2}$/)) {
                    const buffer = Buffer.from(cleanKey, 'base64');
                    hexKey = buffer.toString('hex');
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log('Key is not in base64 format, proceeding with hex');
            }

            // Try to decompress the key if it's compressed
            try {
                const uncompressedKey = ethers.utils.computePublicKey('0x' + hexKey, false);
                hexKey = uncompressedKey.slice(2); // Remove '0x' prefix
            } catch (e) {
                console.log('Key decompression failed, proceeding with original key');
            }

            // Extract coordinates
            return {
                x: '0x' + hexKey.slice(0, 64),
                y: '0x' + hexKey.slice(64, 128),
                decimal: {
                    x: BigInt('0x' + hexKey.slice(0, 64)).toString(10),
                    y: BigInt('0x' + hexKey.slice(64, 128)).toString(10)
                },
                originalKey: publicKey,
                processedKey: hexKey
            };
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Original error:', error);
            throw new Error('Failed to process public key: ' + error.message);
        }
    },

    // Debug function to analyze key format
    analyzeKey: (publicKey) => {
        const cleanKey = publicKey.replace('0x', '').trim();
        return {
            length: cleanKey.length,
            isBase64: cleanKey.match(/^[A-Za-z0-9+/]+={0,2}$/) !== null,
            isHex: /^[0-9A-Fa-f]+$/.test(cleanKey),
            originalKey: publicKey,
            cleanKey: cleanKey
        };
    }
};

Additionally, we generate a rowID using uuid as follows:
import uuid from 'react-native-uuid';

const rowId = uuid.v4().toString();

We are using the following npm packages and versions in our implementation:

"ethers": "^5.7"

"buffer": "^6.0.3"


